# Horizontal scroll using css in custom masonry UI

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I on a quest to create a masonry UI. I tried many samples and many answers in StackOverflow itself but nothing seems to help me.

My situation is this I have a wrapper `ul` which has a height of `height: calc(100vh - 110px);` that can't change there will be some dynamic images inserted to the `li` of this `ul` I want this `li`'s to arrange as the image inside them.

The first method I tried end up giving me this:

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.template-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-left: -8px;
  /* Adjustment for the gutter */
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 0;
}

.template-row li {
  flex: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 150px;
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
  /* Some gutter */
  width: 30%;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="template-row">
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you see above all the `li` has the same height.

The second method I tried:

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.template-row {
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
  height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.template-row li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="template-row">
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-wrap p-10">
    <div class="temp-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you see above all the `li` is aligned properly but the scroll is gone on the page.

Is there any **CSS & HTML** only solution that I can use for my situation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible for you to use an extra wrapper? Then it would be possible by setting the height on the parent and add overflow-y: auto; to this and add the actual list inside this wrapper.

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
}

.template-row {
  height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.template-row__body {
  list-style: none;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
}

.template-row li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="template-row">
  <ul class="template-row__body">
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card-wrap p-10">
      <div class="temp-wrap">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: https://jsfiddle.net/0sapr5m0/15/

Comment: But in this fiddle on full screen when you check you can see that the image with less width is not properly wrapped in the `div` its parent is wider than the `img`

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You could fix that by setting the **img** to 100%. Then those will stretch proportionally to it's parents.

See my edited code snippet above.

Comment: Please check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/0sapr5m0/, even though I Fixed it to `column-count: 3` it's still giving out to be `2 column`  can you fix this.

Comment: See my jsfiddle link in my previous answer. Removing display: inline-block; on the list-item solves it. This was causing white-space which was causing the line break.

Comment: That I already tried but it's causing the div to cut off - https://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/0sapr5m0/, check this link

Comment: Do you have the possibility to use flexbox instead? In your first example you didn't include the padding and box-shadow. In Chrome this is a "bug" while using css-columns.

Comment: If there is a solution in  `flexbox` i would be glad to use it. Thank you fro your effort.

Comment: I will go with this. I will adjust this with my UI, Ty for your efforts. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the layout using flexbox. This should be it.

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
}

.template-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: .5rem; /* Fix box shadow at top, edit to your own values */
}

.template-row__body {
  list-style: none;
  display: inherit;
  flex-flow: inherit;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  margin: -.5em; /* Corrects column margin */
}

.template-column {
  margin: .5em; /* Column gap */
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 1em);
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em; /* Column gap * 2 */
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding:5px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Fix padding */
}
```

```html
<div class="template-row">
  <div class="template-row__body">
    <div class="template-column">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYSCNFNmxqekF0KMq--WwuuJu9CPZgEhjjlXxW4fKIWnQcBtk_Mg" alt="">
    </div>      

    <div class="template-column">
       <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/21/f3/7e/21f37e120170b6363d24e2ef2d6da223.jpg" alt="">
    </div>  
    
    <div class="template-column">
       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKPMXsTBI8EHKvcJ_DZRPWENgMXgU4O2mOJRv6qYNn3FIXFc1Kzg" alt="">
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```